# How to comment all the uncommented lines in a file using puppet module

Tags: puppet, regex-replace

I have a configuration file which contains commented as well as uncommented lines. I want to comment all the uncommented lines in that file using puppet. Is there any optimal/simple way to do this? Or is there a way to run bash command (maybe sed to replace) via puppet? I am not sure that using bash command is a right approach.

It would be really helpful is someone guides me with this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any optimal/simple way to do this?

There is no built-in resource type or well-known module that specifically ensures that non-blank lines of a file start with a `#` character.

> Or is there a way to run bash command (maybe sed to replace) via puppet?

Yes, the [Exec](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/types/exec.html) resource type.  That's your best bet short of writing a custom resource type.

> I am not sure that using bash command is a right approach.

In a general sense, it's not.  Appropriate, specific resource types are better than `Exec`.  But when you don't have a suitable one and can't be bothered to make one, `Exec` is available.

It might look like this:

```bash
# The file to work with, so that we don't have to repeat ourselves
$target_file = '/etc/ssh/sshd_config'

exec { "Comment uncommented ${target_file} lines":
  # Specifying the command in array form avoids complicated quoting or any
  # risk of Puppet word-splitting the command incorrectly
  command  => ['sed', '-i', '-e', '/^[[:space:]]*[^#]/ s/^/# /', $target_file],

  # If we didn't specify a search path then we would need to use fully-qualified
  # command names in 'command' above and 'onlyif' below
  path     => ['/bin', '/usr/bin', '/sbin', '/usr/sbin'],

  # The file needs to be modified only if it contains any non-blank, uncommented
  # lines.  Testing that via an 'onlyif' ensures that Puppet will not
  # run 'sed' or (more importantly) report the file changed when it does
  # not initially contain any lines that need to be commented
  onlyif   => [['grep', '-q', '^[[:space:]]*[^#]', $target_file]],

  # This is the default provider for any target node where the rest of this
  # resource would work anyway.  Specifying it explicitly will lead to a more
  # informative diagnostic if there is an attempt to apply this resource to
  # a system to which it is unsuited.
  provider => 'posix',
}
```

That does not rely on bash or any other shell to run the commands, but it does rely on `sed` and `grep` being available in one of the specified directories.  In fact, it relies specifically on GNU `sed` or one that supports an `-i` option with the same semantics.  Notably, that does not include BSD-style `sed`, such as you will find on macOS.